# MySQL: hash index vs. table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm have pretty big MySQL table(more than 10 millions of rows, innoDB engine), the table has a field that indicate a row's category(`varchar(40)`), the categories are less than 10.

Now I have two choices:

1. keep the field and make a `hash index` on it.
2. make the field into another `category` table, and link them with a `category_id`

Which one has a better performance and why with these two operations:

1. Query for all categories(I know a seperated table could be faster, but does it really faster a lot? even compare to `hash index`?)
2. Query for all rows that in a specified category(I assume `hash index` should be faster, but not sure, cause someone told me MySQL opitimizer will make table join with small table much faster)

EDIT : I almost never add new categories here.

Comment: what do you mean when you say performance?

Comment: @MVCNoob I mean lower latency, faster query

Answer (score 3):

You can define an index on your category column, and it will make some queries for a specific category much faster (assuming the category you search for doesn't occur in a majority of rows). An index on a varchar works well in this way.

The reason you might create a lookup table for the category name is that if you want to change a category name, you can do that by changing one row in the category lookup table, instead of potentially many thousands of rows in the main table.

By the way, your use of the phrase "hash index" is misplaced. InnoDB does not support hash indexes, only B-tree indexes and fulltext indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but via this SQL ```ADD KEY `enginenameindex`(`engine_name`) USING HASH;``` I can actully add a hash index on a innoDB table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html). And beside that, My wonder is how this hash index works compare to join a very small category table.

Comment: my mistake, the `hash index` can't by applied here, the SQL executed successfully on my cloud IDE but the result turns to be btree index...

Comment: What you want may 'adaptive hash index', build in buffer_pool; And add index on a column with varchar(40) may not a good choice, the key-length is huge, so that the index performance is little bad; table join can performance well if the index is appropriate(cover the used column in SQL); So i think the choice-2 is better.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that for any DB it is faster to check a number (integer) than a string. I believe that the fastest result will be received if you create a X-REF table as you mentioned which converts the strings into a number which is the ID of the big table records, and have this field set as an index.

As stated, you will gain performance by assisting your DB to compare 10M numbers instead of 10M strings.

Also, as Bill Karwin suggests, this will allow you to change/add categories in the most flexible way.

Last, if you don't expect the total number of categories to grow above, say, 2000, you may even make the index field of the big table to be just a two-bytes integer.

Comment: The categories are pretty small, e.g. less than 10 records, and barely changes

Comment: Still, performance-wise, that is what I would do (again, consider at the **processor** level what is more **expensive**, compare two numbers or two strings).